# Empty fields' sorting order issue in ag-grid

Tags: ag-grid

in our release site, we use ag-grid v20.1.0, we have license. So below snapshot, I make 'Tag Number' column sort order as ASC, and in database stored procedure data result, all rows that 'Tag Number' equal empty are returned at last, and in ag-grid, the displayed order is also correct, so in below snapshot, the order is correct.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQkxE.jpg)

But after we upgrade to v25.1.0 in our dev branch code, and we're buying the new version's license(have not got it), the issue is below(see snapshot's description):
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eldJP.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4lFyn.jpg)

**my question is: in database stored procedure data result, the sort is correct, but when display them in ag-grid, the sort is not correct, but we did not write our own logic to display them, I want to know whether the reason is we have new version's license?**

Answer (score 0):

The state of your license does not have any impact on the sorting order of empty values.

There could have been a change in behaviour with respect to sort handling of empty values between versions 20 and 25 though.

You should be able to resolve the issue with either a [Post Sort](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/row-sorting/#post-sort) or implementing a [custom comparator](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/row-sorting/#custom-sorting) that handles empty values the way that you want.